# SQLValue returning error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parameters

I am trying to read a SQLValue into an object property however I am receiving an error of "String not in correct format" The "ModifyBy" property is set to allow nulls. Here is the code that is returning the error (the specific line that is throwing the error is the "ModifyBy" line):

```
 public historycrumb(SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            CreateBy = param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@CreateBy").SqlValue != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@CreateBy").SqlValue.ToString()) : (Int32?)null;
            CreateDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@CreateDateTime").SqlValue.ToString());
            ModifyBy = param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyBy").SqlValue != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyBy").SqlValue.ToString()) : (Int32?)null;
            ModifyDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyDateTime").SqlValue.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What is the value returned by `param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyBy").SqlValue.ToString())` ? Is it a valid Int?

Comment: the value of @ModifyBy initially starts out as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLParameter.SQLValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx) reference

Use just **SQLParameter.Value** to access the C# type for the parameter value.  In the 2nd part at least, where you have verified it is not DBNull.value (ergo, it must be an int).
e.g.

> ModifyBy = param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyBy").SqlValue != DBNull.Value ? param.Single(sp => sp.ParameterName == "@ModifyBy").Value : (Int32?)null;

(note: line wrap for display only)

Comment: Thank you Richard, I had to change SqlValue throughout to Value even though SqlValue works if there is a value